# If proto Foo and proto Bar are exactly the same except the name, can I use Bar to parse serialized Foo messages?

Tags: protocol-buffers

If proto `Foo` and proto `Bar` are exactly the same except the name, can I use `Bar` to parse serialized `Foo` messages?

Comment: Try it, it should work provided there is an exact match in both field-identifiers (field-number) and field-wire-type. Protocol Buffers stores the field-id/wire-type but nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In general, you can always change *names* of things in protobufs without affecting the wire format, as long as you don't change *numbers*.  (Though if you ever encode your protobuf to JSON or some similar encoding, names might matter there.)

In fact, `Bar` could even just contain a subset of the fields in `Foo`, since Protobuf backwards compatibility allows you to add and remove fields.